# Variable is empty when I dump() but isnt really empty when sending emails

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on integrating Slack notifications into my Laravel application to send notifications whenever an action occurs that triggers an email notification. Specifically, I'm trying to send Slack notifications in parallel with email notifications wherever the application sends an email. To achieve this, I'm attempting to retrieve a BCC (blind carbon copy) email address and include it when sending emails. But it shows empty. it only shows emails in line 147 which I have mentioned below. But I need it outside update function. I could make a global variable but I would like to avoid it.

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $travel_request = TravelRequest::findOrFail($request->id);

    $travel_request->status = TravelRequestController::TRAVEL_REQUEST_STATUS_MANAGER_APPROVED;
    $travel_request->approver_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $travel_request->save();

    $useremail = $travel_request->user->first()->email;

    $bcc_user = User::select('email')
        ->join('config', 'email', '=', 'value')
        ->where('config.name', '=', 'bcc_user')
        ->get()->toArray();

    $bcc = '';
    if ($bcc_user) {
        $bcc = $bcc_user[0]["email"];
    }

    $status = 'Approved';

    if ($bcc) {
        Mail::send('emails.travel.managerresult', ['user' => $travel_request->user->first(), 'status' => $status], function ($message) use ($useremail, $bcc) {
            $message->to($useremail)->bcc($bcc)->subject('Travel Approved by Manager');
        });
    } else {
        Mail::send('emails.travel.managerresult', ['user' => $travel_request->user->first(), 'status' => $status], function ($message) use ($useremail) {
            $message->to($useremail)->subject('Travel Approved by Manager');
        });
    }


    // get the travel admins
    $travel_admins = User::select('email')
        ->join('role_dashboard_user', 'role_dashboard_user.user_id', '=', 'dashboard_user.id')
        ->join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'role_dashboard_user.role_id')
        ->where('roles.name', '=', 'travel_admin')
        ->get();


    // send email to travel admins
    foreach ($travel_admins as $user) {
        $email = $user->email;
        dump("line 147",$email);    // ONLY THIS LINE GIVES ME ACTUAL BCC.

        if ($bcc) {
            Mail::send('emails.travel.admin', ['request' => $request], function ($message) use ($email, $bcc) {
                $message->to($email)->bcc($bcc)->subject('Travel Request pending booking');
            });
        } else {
            Mail::send('emails.travel.admin', ['request' => $request], function ($message) use ($email) {
                $message->to($email)->subject('Travel Request pending booking');
            });
        }
    }

    if ($request->returnurl) {
        $route = $request->returnurl;
    } else {
        $route = 'travelmanagerapproval.index';
    }

    return redirect()->route($route)->with('success', 'Request has been approved');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function destroy($id, Request $request)
{
    $travel_request = TravelRequest::findOrFail($id);

    $travel_request->status = TravelRequestController::TRAVEL_REQUEST_STATUS_MANAGER_REJECTED;
    $travel_request->approver_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $travel_request->save();

    $useremail = $travel_request->user->first()->email;

    $bcc_user = User::select('email')
        ->join('config', 'email', '=', 'value')
        ->where('config.name', '=', 'bcc_user')
        ->get()->toArray();

    $bcc = '';
    if ($bcc_user) {
        $bcc = $bcc_user[0]["email"];
    }

    $status = 'Declined';

    if ($bcc) {
        Mail::send('emails.travel.managerresult', ['user' => $travel_request->user->first(), 'status' => $status], function ($message) use ($useremail, $bcc) {
            $message->to($useremail)->bcc($bcc)->subject('Travel Declined');
        });

    } else {
        Mail::send('emails.travel.managerresult', ['user' => $travel_request->user->first(), 'status' => $status], function ($message) use ($useremail) {
            $message->to($useremail)->subject('Travel Declined');
        });
    }

    if ($request->returnurl) {
        $route = $request->returnurl;
    } else {
        $route = 'travelmanagerapproval.index';
    }

    return redirect()->route($route)->with('success', 'Request has been declined');
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm misreading your question, but in line 147, you are dumping $email, not $bcc.

Comment: yes because $bcc is empty ( when I dump(), but sends emails somehow).